# How to assemble a new function out of existing functions?

Tags: matlab

I have a function kappa that contains two other functions sigma_ and sigma__.
The error I get is

```
error: binary operator '.^' not implemented for 'function handle' by 'scalar' operations
error: called from
at line -1 column -1
```

My code is

```
>> syms epsilon
>> a =  0.36990
>> b =  2.6474
>> sigma = @(epsilon) 10 .^ (a * log (epsilon) + b)
>> sigma_=@(epsilon) diff(sigma)
>> sigma__=@(epsilon) diff(sigma_)
>> kappa=@(epsilon) (sigma__)/(1+sigma_.^2).^(3/2)

>> kappa(1)
error: binary operator '.^' not implemented for 'function handle' by'scalar' operations
error: called from
at line -1 column -1
```

I edited my code:

```
>> sigma_ = @(epsilon) diff (sigma (epsilon))
>> sigma__=@(epsilon) diff(sigma_(epsilon))
>> sigma_(1)
ans = [](0x0)
>> kappa=@(epsilon) (sigma__(epsilon))/(1+sigma_(epsilon).^2).^(3/2)
>> kappa(1)
ans = [](0x0)
```

Comment: Ignoring the confusing function naming, each of your `sigma*` functions take one argument, but you don't pass an argument to any of them. Try `sigma(epsilon)` (in 4 different places).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I edited my code, but now it returns an empty set

Comment: Yes, because `diff` of a scalar value is null.

Comment: I found the answer - I was using the operator.
https://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/differentiation.html